# How to add latest Julia version to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: anaconda, julia, jupyter

I installed Julia 1.5.3 on my Linux Mint 20 system. I copied the Julia files in `julia-1.5.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`  to `/opt/julia-1.5.3/`, adjacent to the folder `/opt/julia-1.4.1/`, (I did not change the path environment variable in `.bashrc`).

I ran `Pkg.add("IJulia")`in the Julia console.

So far so good, the new version runs if I start Julia from the command prompt. Atom / Juno also run the latest version.

But, if I run Jupyter from the Anaconda navigator, then I only see the older version of Julia, see this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG1TH.png

How can I add julia-1.5.3 to that menu?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you installed IJulia, the Julia package which runs the jupyter kernel? If not that's what you're missing.

If you've got that already but you have updated your Julia version and can only see the old Julia kernel, You need to `Pkg.build("IJulia")` or `] build IJulia` in pkg repl mode as the build script registers the kernel.

EDITED to add:

As this answer has received quite a few views and votes now, I'll add that in addition to running the build script there's also an `installkernel` function exported by IJulia which gives you more control over what type of kernel you want to add to Jupyter. As an example, a multithreaded kernel can be added like this:

```
installkernel("Julia (4 threads)", env = Dict("JULIA_NUM_THREADS" => "4"))
```

Here the first argument is the kernel name which will be displayed in the Jupyter GUI, and the `Dict` sets the environment variable needed to start a multi-threaded Julia process.

Comment: As per https://juliapackages.com/p/ijulia the command for package mode is `] add IJulia`, the variant using `build` did not work for me (Julia 1.9.3).

Comment: Just tried on Julia 1.9.3, works fine for me (indeed I would be very surprised if `build` didn't work, as it's part of the `Pkg` API and shouldn't change for any Julia 1.x version - https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/api/#Pkg.build). The difference between `add` and `build` is that `add` only calls `build` when a package gets installed for the first time, so if you `add IJulia` when it's already installed it won't build again, and you need to either `build` or manually add a kernel using `installkernel`.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following if you already have Julia and Jupyter installed

1. open julia in terminal
2. ] build IJulia
3. using IJulia
4. notebook()

Comment: `using IJulia`  alone did the trick.  already had a jupyter notebook installed, so `notebook()` wasn't necessary. `] build IJulia` produced a syntax error.