# Add latest version of Julia to Anaconda JupyterLab?

Tags: julia, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151297/how-to-add-latest-julia-version-to-jupyter-notebook) discussion, but does it apply to me? I just installed Anaconda (on Ubuntu 21.10), and the JupyterLab upon launch offers my older version of Julia 1.6.1. I just moved the latest Julia 1.6.4 to my `~/opt/` directory and updated by `.bashrc`. What should I do to have Anaconda see and offer this latest Julia version?

Comment: Exactly as in the answer you linked? Did it not work for you?

Comment: That did it! I just wasn't sure if I should do it that way.

Comment: Do you want to call Python from Julia or Julia from Python?
In most cases this tutorial should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python/64241265#64241265

Comment: If this is just Jupyter Lab, normally strating Julia, and `using IJulia;notebook(".")` should make your Anaconda to see Julia. (config files are getting generated).